# How to remove the top and bottom white spaces of the Python graph in power bi?

Tags: python, powerbi

I have created the following graph in Power BI using a Python Script. But, I am not able to remove the top and bottom white spaces. Any help on how to remove them?

[Sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPBPU.png)

Comment: what visual library are you using?

Comment: using matplotlib. this is done.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar Please include your script.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the resizing parameter and get it solved.